# Print label using IEEE 1284 - USB Port and Zebra stripe S500

Tags: c#, printing, libusb, zebra-printers, zebra-striping

My company is doing upgrade the system. Everything should be fine until I had to deal with our old label printer.
They have used Zebra Label Printer model: Stripe S500

[image]

About the PC, we've upgraded to the new one,therefor IEEE 1284 doesn't exist anymore, just ethernet and usb connections supported. I decide to connect the old printer to the new PC, but one problem I'm facing right now is :

- I cannot send data to the printer by using C# code. Here is my device manager  display, it said No Printer attached.

[image]

Could anyone help me please. I want to know how to use C# to send a text content to the label printer.

Thank you,

Comment: You can't send data to the printer until Windows knows there's a printer there. This isn't a programming question; it's an OS question, and it should be asked on [su]. Once you can see the printer in *Devices and Printers*, you can worry about how to print to it from code. Before then, you're not going to be able to do so. If the connection type is not supported, either use an older computer where it's available or upgrade to a newer printer. (And what possible use do you think posting an image of the printer is, other than a waste of space? The physical appearance of the printer is useless.)

Comment: Buy a new printer.  You have already spent more money in terms of your time by trying to fix this one.

Comment: Buy a $10 dollar "USB to IEEE 1284" dongle. After it is installed correctly a Parallel Port will be listed in the Device Manager. Then a printer driver can be added (*assuming* there is a supported driver for the Printer for Windows 7 or 8..) and C# can print to that. Since it is an old printer there might *not* be a modern compatible driver. YMMV, and it is something to research. It also might be worthwhile just to get a modern USB-capable printer with manufacture support for your particular OS.

Comment: See http://www.fixya.com/support/t12707629-change_parallel_port_usb_zebra_printer , etc.

Comment: @user2864740, I've tried that before asking this question. It didn't work